# RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-lightning

I tried all the solutions I could to solve this...but still no luck. Here is the error I am getting.

````
    results = self.trainer.run_pretrain_routine(model)
  File "/mnt/beegfs/scratch/nahmed/eICU-GNN-LSTM_working/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1239, in run_pretrain_routine
    self.train()
  File "/mnt/beegfs/scratch/nahmed/eICU-GNN-LSTM_working/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 394, in train
    self.run_training_epoch()
  File "/mnt/beegfs/scratch/nahmed/eICU-GNN-LSTM_working/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 491, in run_training_epoch
    batch_output = self.run_training_batch(batch, batch_idx)
  File "/mnt/beegfs/scratch/nahmed/eICU-GNN-LSTM_working/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 839, in run_training_batch
    opt_closure_result = self.optimizer_closure(
  File "/mnt/beegfs/scratch/nahmed/eICU-GNN-LSTM_working/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 1014, in optimizer_closure
    training_step_output = self.training_forward(split_batch, batch_idx, opt_idx,
  File "/mnt/beegfs/scratch/nahmed/eICU-GNN-LSTM_working/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 1216, in training_forward
    output = self.model.training_step(*args)
  File "/mnt/beegfs/scratch/nahmed/eICU-GNN-LSTM_working/train_ns_lstmgnn.py", line 78, in training_step
    in_x = self.dataset.data.x[n_id].to(self.device)
RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)```
I am trying to run the code in GPU in the HPC server. Please someone help.
````

Comment: What exactly you do not understand here (error is very clear), and what exactly did you try?

Comment: by explicitly assigning the device to cuda like this cuda = torch.device('cuda')...But no luck

Comment: assigning the device of what? The error clearly says that the indices should be in the CPU, not in your CUDA device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved it by this, self.dataset.data.x should be in the same device as the indices.

in_x = self.dataset.data.x.to(n_id.device)[n_id].to(self.device)

Hope it helps someone.